# How can I make sure a branch gets duplicated in my development and main branches in TFVC?

Tags: version-control, versioning, branching, team-foundation-server, merging

I inherited a Visual Studio solution with a Main branch, a QA branch off of Main, and a DEV branch off of QA. It seems these are the only branches and they've existed for the lifespan of the solution. The solution has 5 projects, and in our new version I want to create a different behavior for one of the projects, but then have it go back to the old behavior for subsequent versions. So my plan is to branch that project and then not merge it back.

If I branch the project in DEV, will that new branch also be reflected in QA and Main?

When I tried researching this question, I came across this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc

It talks about development isolation and feature isolation but doesn't explain how to do both at once.

I apologize if this seems cryptic but my reason for having different behavior in this one version is very complicated and could easily triple the length of this question and is largely irrelevant. So given that I do need a one-off modification to one of my projects, what's the best way to do what I'm trying to do?